# Adobe CQ / AEM Link Checker Transformer does not strip HTML extension

Tags: aem, aem-6

When adding relative path for a link to text in a rich text component, the '.html' is append on saving. The `Day CQ Link Checker Transformer` has the property `Strip HTML Extension` enabled. By doing this I would expect the `.html` to be remove but it is not.

[image]
How would one prevent the `.html` appending on relative paths added to rich text components?

Also, if it is an external url and the protocol is not present, the `http://` is pre-appended by default when the required is to be `https://`. How to make it pre-append `https://` instead of `http://`

Comment: have you checked the link checker configuration is applicable to Author runmode as well?

Comment: @SumantaPakira it is the same for author and publisher.

Comment: then you might have some custom rewriter code because out-of-the-box installation does remove .html extension and also it does not add any http protocol. In out-of-the-box installation if you add external link e.g google.com then link checker will mark it as invalid url

Comment: There is custom rewrite code but it doesn't apply to this component. I cleared caches, recompiled JSPs, tried with different browsers, added debug logs to the custom rewrite code and it is never used by a rich text component. The `.html` being appended to the relative path, happens before saving the component but after the text is linked to a relative path.

Comment: you can add custom code and config for better understanding

Comment: Custom functionality was created to address this.